# graphql-upload data does not work when I try to send it to the server

Tags: javascript, file-upload, graphql, multipartform-data, form-data

When using graphql-upload and then I try to send the return data to a flask python server, the data always ends up in the body instead of the file. The header is automatically set successfully to `content-type: multipart/form-data boundary etc....` when I use the below graphql connector.

I based a lot of the below on this example https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples/blob/master/api/resolvers.mjs

```
async fileUpload(page, id, file) {
  const { filename, mimetype, createReadStream } = await file;
  const stream = await createReadStream();

  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', JSON.stringify({
    filename, mimetype, stream
  }));

  // form.append('file', stream)); // this attempt fails as well

  const url = `/${page}/${id}/file`;

  return this.post(
    url,
    null,
    {
      body: form
    }
  );
}
```

My schema looks like so:

```
  type File {
    id: ID!
    page: String!
    name: String
    url: String!
  }

  input FileUploadInput {
    id: ID!
    page: String!
    files: [Upload!]!
  }

  extend type Mutation {
    fileUpload(data: FileUploadInput!): File
  }
```

Resolver

```
const { GraphQLUpload } = require('graphql-upload');

const singleFileUpload  (
  root,
  { data: { id, page, files } },
  { dataSources }
) => dataSources.files.fileUpload(id, page, files[0]);

module.exports = {
  Upload: GraphQLUpload,
  Mutation: {
    singleFileUpload
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the read stream provided by graphql wasn't working but saving the file locally, then creating a readStream for that file was successful.

```
    const { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
    const stream = await createReadStream();

    const { path } = await saveLocally(stream, filename); // this function pipes the stream to save it locally

    const newFile = await fs.createReadStream(path);

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append(
      'file',
      newFile
    );

    // I delete the file after I received a succesful response.
    await fs.unlink(path, (err, res) => {
      if (err) return err;
      return res;
    });
```